# VS2012: Breakpoint in ntdll.dll at debugger launch with no more info

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Occasionally when I launch/debug my application in Debug mode, using VS2012, I get a dialog:

> <blahblah.exe> has triggered a breakpoint.

It contains no other information, so I hit break to see what's going on. Oh, but then I get "wntdll.pdb not loaded", and no other information on the problem. The call stack points at ntdll.dll, and it appears my application hasn't even begun execution yet at this point.

Choosing continue at this point will let the application/debugger continue as usual.

This occurs very frequently (about 7 launches out of 10). I'm running Windows 8 (64-bit), and Visual Studio 2012 with update 1.

Previously I had Windows 7 (64-bit) and VS2010, and never got this problem. This particular project has been upgraded from the version it was created in (2010), so maybe that's part of the issue.

Anyone run into this problem before? I've no idea where to start looking for a cause. Though I'm running a 64-bit Windows, I should mention that I'm building a 32-bit application.

**Update:**
After enabling Microsoft Symbol Servers, here's what the call stack looks like:

```
>   ntdll.dll!_LdrpDoDebuggerBreak@0()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitializeProcess@8()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__LdrpInitialize@8()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitialize@8()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_LdrInitializeThunk@8()   Unknown
```

I should also add, just in case, that I definitely have *no breakpoints set* manually anywhere in my code.

Comment: Enable the Microsoft Symbol server so you get symbols for all Windows functions.  You'll get a decently annotated call stack.  Post it in your question if it doesn't help.

Comment: Thought I tried it, but I didn't realize I had to open the settings and choose "load all symbols" first.

Comment: Did you have >=2 versions of VS installed on the machine when this issue occurred?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This annoying issue stems from a bug within Visual Studio:

> What's happening is that we're not correctly handling multiple loader
>   breakpoint events from different processes simultaneously. The OS
>   triggers a loader breakpoint once the process is up and running but
>   before any execution can take place for debuggers to instanciate
>   breakpoints and take other action. Normally we successfully ignore
>   these (at least in the single launch case). You can work around this
>   by disabling the "Break all processes when one process breaks"
>   checkbox in tools->options->debugger. Also note that this isn't a
>   fatal error. We're just stopping at an internal breakpiont and you can
>   just hit F5 again to keep going.
>
> It's a race condition so won't be that easy for us to track down and
>   multi-launch usage in VS is fairly low so I'm going to won't fix this
>   assuming the workaround above will be good enough to get you unblocked
>   and we'll revisit this if we see more reports from additional
>   customers. Does that sound reasonable to you?
>
> Thanks again for the feedback.
>
> Marc Paine Visual Studio Debugger Engineering Manager

Source: [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1059502/visual-studio-2013-update-4-issues-debug-break-with-multiple-startup-projects)

I followed the advice for disabling the "Break all processes when one process breaks" checkbox in the Visual Studio Debugger settings and this "removed" the issue for now.

Perhaps if we can get a few more people to report the same issue/annoyance of this bug, Microsoft will eventually fix it like they suggest.

Comment: This bug had been annoying me for quite some time as well, but I only found that Microsoft Connect article about it recently after some deeper searching. I'm happy for now that this workaround exists.

Comment: I started randomly get this annoying break in the middle of nowhere for no apparent reason and google led me to this reply. Disabling that checkbox helps. By the way, ms connect link is dead now.

Comment: Still around in VS2019.  We are spawning multiple processes to make up one "application".  In order to debug this we have to install the "Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool".  That's a very helpful extension, but it seems to cause this problem every time the solution is run, and stops anywhere from zero times (infrequent) to 5 times (frequent) or more (infrequent.  Easy to walk off to get coffee and get back and it's gone nowhere. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you run the application under a debugger, there is an automatic breakpoint as soon as the process starts. This breakpoint gives you the opportunity to set further breakpoints before the process begins executing. If you don't like it, there is usually an option in the debugger to ignore the initial default breakpoint. For example, in `cdb` [the option is `-g`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539058(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Out of curiosity, then why should it only break in 7 out of 10 cases? Shouldn't it break every time?

Comment: @OregonGhost I have no explanation for that. But the breakpoint you hit is the default initial breakpoint. You can configure whether the initial breakpoint should be respected or ignored.

Comment: This seems to me more of a race issue.  As I stated above in my comment, my application with multiple processes can hit this breakpoint anywhere from zero times at startup to 5 or greater.  There are about 15 processes that comprise the application.

Answer (score 0):

I just found myself encountering a similar issue, though, this was my callstack:

```
ntdll.dll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak()
ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeProcess()
ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitialize() 
ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk()
```

In my case, my Visual Studio Solution has several projects, with three of those projects set to Start (and Debug) through the Solution's "Multiple startup projects" setting.

Two of the start up projects are (Unmanaged) C++, and one of them is C#. I was able to get rid of this startup breakpoint by opening the project properties for the C# project, and enabling "native code debugging".

[image: "Enable native code debugging" checkbox]

**Edit**: Apparently this did not fully solve my problem, it only greatly reduced the frequency of it occurring. However, I think the same general solution might still fix it.

One of the other projects in this Solution is just a prebuilt binary that's being launched by manually specifying the binary as the project's `TargetPath`.

Changing the `Debugger Type` to `Native Only` in the project's `Debugging` property page seems to have helped as well.

[image: "Native Only" Debugger type]

So, changing *both* of these appears to have actually solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

See if you have turned on breaking into the debugger on first chance exceptions.

You can see this under "Debug/Exceptions...". See if any of the boxes are checked. (At least this was the menu location in the older VS variants - I don't have VS 2012 currently)
If enabled, this causes the debugger to break when an exception is thrown even though it may be handled correctly by the application. If disabled, the debugger only breaks when the exception is not handled. If any exceptions are checked, try unchecking them and see if this persists.