# Debugger in Visual Studio stops at LdrpDoDebuggerBreak

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

The Visual Studio debugger stops each time at the very beginning of the program at the LdrpDoDebuggerBreak when debugging starts. If you press F5 (Debug> Continue), the program will continue to run and run normally under the debugger. It is very annoying that every time you start debugging, you need to press F5 twice with an interval of several seconds and the application window does not popup automatically.

This behavior appeared a few days ago. Previously, the application did not stop at the very beginning but started immediately. And its window popped up to the very top. Something has changed in the Visual Studio settings, but I can't figure out what.

Visual Studio version: 16.9.0 (latest at this moment).

Call stack at this breakpoint:

```
ntdll.dll! LdrpDoDebuggerBreak () Unknown
ntdll.dll! LdrpInitializeProcess () Unknown
ntdll.dll! _LdrpInitialize () Unknown
ntdll.dll! LdrpInitialize () Unknown
ntdll.dll! LdrInitializeThunk () Unknown
```

What settings affect this debugger behavior? How do I get it back to its previous behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376523/vs2012-breakpoint-in-ntdll-dll-at-debugger-launch-with-no-more-info

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible sample with us?

Comment: Maybe you could try to reset your vs settings under Tools-->Options-->Import and Export  Settings-->Reset all settings.

Comment: I've come across this as well. Any solution?